# salt 3003: Loop over pillar contents

Tags: python-3.x, salt-stack

What is the Salt 3003 (Python 3) syntax to do the following

```
{% for group, args in pillar['groups.developers'].iteritems() %}
{{ group }}:
  group.present:
    - name: {{ group }}
{% if 'gid' in args %}
    - gid: {{ args['gid'] }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where `developers` is:

```
#./pillar/base/user/developers.sls
groups:
  developers:
    developer-a:
      - fullname: Developer A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
{% for group, args in salt['pillar.get']('groups:developers', {}).items() %}
{{ group }}:
  group.present:
    - name: {{ group }}
{% if 'gid' in args %}
    - gid: {{ args['gid'] }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Use `items()` instead of `iteritems()`.

[More information about pillar](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html)